# Wordpress the_title(); showing incorrect value in foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I was processing posts in a `foreach()` loop, but it seems that `the_title()` is calling onto a single post throughout the whole loop.

For example; It should show `Kim`, `Nick`, and `Evan`.
But it would only show `Nick`, `Nick` and `Nick`.

Here is my code:

```
<?php get_header();?>
<?php 
/**
 * Template Name: Team Members
 */

the_post();

// Get 'team' posts
$team_posts = get_posts( array(
'post_type' => 'members',
'posts_per_page' => -1, // Unlimited posts
'orderby' => 'title', // Order alphabetically by name
) );

/* On going work to reorganize the member part */
$web = array();
$cloud = array();
$prof = array();

foreach ($team_posts as $post) {
setup_postdata($post);
if ( get_field('group') == '1')
{
    array_push($web, $post);
} elseif ( get_field('group') == '2'){
    array_push($cloud, $post);
} else {
    array_push($prof, $post);
}
}

function display($array){
foreach ( $array as $post ): 
setup_postdata($post);

$thumb_src = null;
if ( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ) {
    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'team-thumb' );
    $thumb_src = $src[0];
}
?>
<article class="col-sm-6 profile">
    <div class="profile-header">
        <?php if ( $thumb_src ) { ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $thumb_src; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>, <?php the_field('position'); ?>" class="img-circle">
        <?php } else { ?>
        <img src="http://static2.bigstockphoto.com/thumbs/6/9/3/small2/3969472.jpg" alt="No Image" class="img-circle">
        <?php } ?>
    </div>

    <div class="profile-content">
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php //if( $email = get_field('email')): ?>
            <a href="mailto:<?php echo antispambot( get_field('email') ); ?>"><img src=<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/glyphs/email.png'?>></a>
        <?php //endif; ?>
    </div>
</article><!-- /.profile -->
<?php endforeach;
}


if ( $team_posts ):
?>
<section class="row profiles">
    <div class="intro">
        <p class ="lead">
            "Meet the individuals behind UWB CSS/Bio"
        </p>
    </div>

    <h2>Professor</h2>
    <?php display($prof); ?>
    <h2>Cloud Computing Group</h2>
    <?php display($cloud); ?>
    <h2>Web Group</h2>
    <?php display($web); ?>

</section><!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: I forgot to add that the_content(); gets the correct data.

Answer (score 1):

"the_title()" can only be used inside "The Loop". With your custom function and loop you are outside of the context.

You should try to use "get_the_title( $ID );" with parsing the ID of the post as a variable and you will get the title back.

Comment: the strange part is that the_content(); words fine. It gets the correct data. only the_title(); is working weird right now

Comment: Did you try get_the_title ($post->ID ) ?

Comment: the title only works inside the loop, which means you need to "while" your get_posts(). To access in a foreach, should be something like $post->title

Answer (score 0):

Use wp_reset_query before the foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Use `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>` and `<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>` at the end of while loop.
For more details you can refer these below links:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query

This will makes your life easy. May be!